# Cucumber 4 Optional Words?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber-java

```
@Then("a topic is (not) displayed on the chat icon of the menu")
```

Basically I want the not to be optional if possible?  Previously it was (is|is not).

Adding that is|is not is part of the capturing group, entered as a String in the stepdef.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use regular expressions you should start your strings with `^` and/or end them with `$`. Otherwise Cucumber will treat them as [Cucumber expressions](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/). So:

```java
@Then("^a topic (is|is not) displayed on the chat icon of the menu$")
public void a_topic_is_displayed(String isDisplayed){

}
```

If you do want to use Cucumber expressions then you'll have to capture the modifier in a parameter type. So:

```java
@Then("a topic {isOrIsNot} displayed on the chat icon of the menu")
public void a_topic_is_displayed(boolean isDisplayed){

}
```

And you'd register a parameter type to convert the string to a boolean:

```java
typeRegistry.defineParameterType(new ParameterType<>(
    "isOrIsNot",                     // name
    "is|is not",                     // regexp
    boolean.class,                   // type
    (String arg) -> "is".equals(arg) // transformer function
))
```

Comment: Thank you sir, exactly what I needed!

Comment: M.P. Korstanje is it possible that optional capturing group within stepdef defined using regular expression invokes somehow type parameters? I'm currently struggling with such situation...  
  
Before I moved from cucumber-jvm 2.X to 5.X absence of optional text in gherkin step caused that method argument got null value. Now I'm getting error
**IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments**  
  
I thought that defined steps which use regular expression will not be affected by introducing cucumber expressions but it looks like they are...

Comment: If you have defined a cucumber expression, then it will only interact with the steps where it is defined. Providing you have defined it correctly such as was explained above.